# How can I generalise Coq proofs of an iff?

Tags: coq

A common kind of proof I have to make is something like

```
Lemma my_lemma : forall y, (forall x x', Q x x' y) -> (forall x x', P x y <-> P x' y).
Proof.
  intros y Q_y.
  split.
  + <some proof using Q>
  + <the same proof using Q, but x and x' are swapped>
```

where `Q` is itself some kind of iff-shaped predicate.

My problem is that the proofs of `P x y -> P x' y` and `P x' y -> P x y` are often basically identical, with the only difference between that the roles of `x` and `x'` are swapped between them. Can I ask Coq to transform the goal into

```
forall x x', P x y -> P x' y
```

which then generalises to the iff case, so that I don't need to repeat myself in the proof?

I had a look through the standard library, the tactic index, and some SO questions, but nothing told me how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a custom tactic for it:

```
Ltac sufficient_if :=
  match goal with
  | [ |- forall (x : ?t) (x' : ?t'), ?T <-> ?U ] =>    (* If the goal looks like an equivalence (T <-> U) (hoping that T and U are sufficiently similar)... *)
    assert (HHH : forall (x : t) (x' : t'), T -> U);   (* Change the goal to (T -> U) *)
      [ | split; apply HHH ]                           (* And prove the two directions of the old goal  *)
  end.

Parameter Q : nat -> nat -> nat -> Prop.
Parameter P : nat -> nat -> Prop.
Lemma my_lemma : forall y, (forall x x', Q x x' y) -> (forall x x', P x y <-> P x' y).
Proof.
  intros y Q_y.
  sufficient_if.
```

Answer (score 2):

In mathematics, one often can make "assumptions" *"without loss of generality"* (WLOG) to simplify proofs of this kind.  In your example, you could say "assume *without loss of generality* that `P x y` holds.  To prove `P x y <-> P x' y` it is sufficient to prove `P x' y.`"

If you are using `ssreflect`, you have the [`wlog` tactic](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ssreflect-proof-language.html#variants-the-suff-and-wlog-tactics).

You essentially `cut` in another goal which can easily solve your goal. You can also do it with standard tactics like `assert` or `enough` (which is like `assert` but the proof obligations are in the other order).

An example to show what I mean:  below I just want to show the implication in one direction, because it can easily solve the implication in the other direction (with `firstorder`).

```
Context (T:Type) (P:T->T->Prop).

Goal forall x y, P x y <-> P y x.

  enough (forall x y, P x y -> P y x) by firstorder.
```

Now I just have to show the goal in one direction, because it implies the real goal's both directions.

For more about WLOG see for instance [1](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejrh13/papers/wlog.pdf)